# Second Ethernet card: ¿the same collision domain?

Tags: network-adapter

I would like your help to understand if installing a second NIC means another collision domain, or if it acts like another port in a hub (inside my PC).

Comment: It will not act like a hub... each NIC will have a different IP address and will not communicate one to another inside the PC without some special routing taking place. They will be on the same broadcast domain (collision domains are kind of a thing of the past) if you connect them to the same network, but two distinct interfaces. What are trying to accomplish? Without something special this will not bridge networks,  increase your speed or performance, or provide resiliency.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, do they act out like two VLANs? At work, we have two separated systems with the same  subnet (192.168.0.1/16). I want to avoid IP conflicts when I access repeated IPs on my browser. It  is not possible to change IPs un one of the two networks because th ey are in 24/7 producción.

Comment: Every networking adapter is used to manage a video processor, which has a bulit-in web server to control their parameters

Comment: I am still not understanding... VLAN's are a different thing, they allow multiple subnets to exist in the same physical LAN topology with separation. I still don't understand why you have two NICs if they connected to the same subnet, all you are going to do is slow things down because Windows will get confused with the same subnet on two network adapters. Is this in a corporate environment? If so, this is off topic and you should contact your corporate IT staff, the possible implications in corporate environment are too complex to deal with in this situation.

Comment: Hi Acejavelin! Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Hi Acejavelin! Sorry for not being clear. My need is to manage two different LAN which unfortunately have the same network segment (192.168.0.0/16) with many repeated IPs. At present, I use two PCs to access each one, but I want to do it with only one PC. Each of IP is a porfessional video TV controller, whose controls are in their built-in web server. That's the reason I have to manage the through web browser.

Comment: The problem is the OS won't know which adapter to use if both subnets have duplicates but are unique. The only reliable way to do this I can think of with a VM tied directly to an adapter. The "right way" to do this is re-IP one of the networks so they don't conflict with each other,  then it would be simple.

Comment: I understand, acejavelin. Thank you for all you help!